# How do I change the permissions for my USBs?

Tags: 12.10, usb, permissions, 32-bit

For some reason I have discovered that I can no longer edit any of the data I have on my USBs. I was once able to edit it and I am able to edit the data on it on other PCs. I am running 32 bit 12.10 if this detail is required.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had this happen to me sometimes, and mostly when I use FAT formatted flash drives.

Can you copy files to it using the terminal, could it be related to [this bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nautilus/+bug/1021375)?

Most of the times that this used to happen to me, I was able to solve it by plugging it into a Windows machine, and using checkdisk on it (or whatever it was called, haven't used it for a while).

<sub>Just realized now, I never tried to use Ubuntu's fsck, and I have no idea why.</sub>

Comment: No it isn't that bug as this is the error I receive when I do copy files to it using the terminal: cp: cannot create regular file `/media/brentonhorne/0CF1-B736/jkon.m': Read-only file system

Comment: I used my Windows Vista machine to clean it and it worked so I'll accept your answer, thanks.

Comment: Was going to ask you to try using fsck, but I guess I was too late :p